# Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

Tags: java, android

I am using this tutorial [here](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)
and when I add this section of code directly into my OnCreate class I get the above error

```
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);

try {
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database");
}

try {
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();
} catch(SQLException sqle){
    throw sqle;
}
```

I am still pretty new so any help and pointing in the right direction is most appreciated.

Comment: when you get compiler errors or runtime exceptions, *add them to your question*

Comment: What does the stacktrace in the log say? It should indicate where it is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `DataBaseHelper` a valid `Context`.  You'll probably want to pass it the main Activity (or `this` if it is in the Activity).

Comment: I see it now.  You threw me off with the `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(null);` line above it. You can get rid of it.  Perhaps removing that line altogether will fix it.

Comment: if i take that away it says myDBHelper cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Remove both `myDbHelper` instantiation lines then use `DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);`

Answer (score 0):

To get more information about the exception, try "chaining" the thrown Error with the caught IOException:

```
catch (IOException ioe) {
    throw new Error("Unable to create database", ioe);
}
```

That should show you the `SQLException` that is being thrown.